# usage of sum function in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
x_d = np.linspace(-4, 8, 30)

print('x_d shape: ',x_d.shape)
print('x shape: ',x.shape)


density = sum((abs(xi - x_d) < 0.5) for xi in x)---------> difficulty in understanding statement
```

---

```
output:

x_d shape:  (30,)
x shape:  (20,)
```

I am having difficulty in understanding above statement

for each value of x we are substracting x_d from it, and we will get single value. But we are density as (30,)

How we got density dimension as (30,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
xi - x_d
```

will use NumPy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to conform the shapes of the two objects. In this case it means treating the scalar value `xi` as if it was an array of all the same value and of equal dimensions as `x_d`.

The `abs` function and the less-than comparison will work element-wise with NumPy arrays, so that the expression

```
(abs(xi - x_d) < 0.5)
```

should result in a length-30 array (same size as `x_d`) where each entry of that array is either `True` or `False` depending on the condition applied to each element of `x_d`.

This gets repeated for multiple values of `xi`, leading to multiple different length-30 arrays.

The result of calling `sum` on these arrays is that they are added together elementwise (and also by the luck of broadcasting, since the `sum` function has a default initial value of 0, the first array is added to 0 elementwise, leaving it unchanged).

So in the final result, it will be a length-30 array, where item 0 of the array counts how many `xi` values satisfied the absolute value condition based on the 0th element of `x_d`. Item 1 of the output array will count the number of `xi` values that satisfied the absolute value condition on the 1st element of `x_d`, and so on.

Here is an example with some test data:

```
In [31]: x_d = np.linspace(-4, 8, 30)

In [32]: x = np.arange(20)

In [33]: x
Out[33]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])

In [34]: density = sum((abs(xi - x_d) < 0.5) for xi in x)

In [35]: density
Out[35]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: thanks for response. I didn't understand statement. 'This gets repeated for multiple values of xi, leading to multiple different length-30 arrays'. For loop is repeated for each element of x which in this case so we get list of 20 arrays of shape(30,) for each element of x and we are summing all 20 arrays of shape(30). Is my understanding right. By the way is there is a way to print each array of length 30 for each of value of x? . Thanks

Comment: Imagine taking only the first value of `x` (the first iteration of the loop inside of `sum`). Let's pretend this value is 0. Then you will compute `0 - x_d`. In NumPy, this results in an array that has the values `[0 - x_d[0], 0 - x_d[1], ...]`. So we get a length-30 array for that iteration. Let's put it in the back of our mind and move on to the next iteration, which will come from the entry `x[1]` (the second entry in `x`). We repeat the process and get `[x[1] - x_d[0], x[1] - x_d[1], ...]`. So inside `sum`, each pass of the loop is creating a whole length-30 array for that iteration.

Comment: If you want to print what the intermediate arrays are you can use `for xi in x: print((abs(xi - x_d) < 0.5))`. You could even manually save 3 of them into a list, like this: `test = [(abs(x[0] - x_d) < 0.5), (abs(x[1] - x_d) < 0.5), (abs(x[2] - x_d) < 0.5)]`, and then try `sum(test)` to see what happens.

Comment: thanks for help. Now it helps to understand statement.